# Inject autommaper mapper using NInject

Tags: c#, ninject, automapper

I want to inject a `AutoMapper.IMapper` single instance as a `singleton` using NInject.

Actually, I'm un/mapping from/to objects using the [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) static API. It's turned out obsolete and I'm looking forward to taking advantage of the ocassion to inject it using [NInject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Currently, I'm using this code in order to create my `IMapper` instance:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.DigitalResourceProfile());
AutoMapper.Mapper.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.DigitalInputProfile());
AutoMapper.Mapper.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.FollowUpActivityProfile());
AutoMapper.Mapper.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.ResourceProfile());
```

As you can see, I've some profiles to initialize as well.

How should I build all that?

Until now, I've only been able to create a `Module` but I don't know how to make the bindings up.

```
public class AutoMapperModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration>().ToProvider<AutoMapperconfigurationProvider>().InSingletonScope();
        this.Bind<AutoMapper.IMapper>().To<AutoMapper.Mapper>();

    }

    private class AutoMapperconfigurationProvider : IProvider<AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration>
    {

        public object Create(IContext context)
        {
            AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration instance = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.DigitalResourceProfile());
                    cfg.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.DigitalInputProfile());
                    cfg.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.FollowUpActivityProfile());
                    cfg.AddProfile(new UI.Mappings.Profiles.ResourceProfile());
                }
            );

            return instance;
        }

        public Type Type
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to write this sentence each time I need a `IMapper` to map objects:

```
IMapper mapper = kernel.Get<IMapper>();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not obsolete anymore, I put it back FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this.

And I found the following:

In documentation we can found that we can do something like:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<SomeProfile>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper(); // option 1
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config); // option 2
```

Your code would work with using the `option 2`, because you have binding for `configuration` and for `mapper`.

But here we have two problems.
1) You need to change your first binding to bind `MapperConfiguration` as an interface `IConfigurationProvider` because the constructor of `Mapper` needs it:

```
public Mapper(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    : this(configurationProvider, configurationProvider.ServiceCtor)
{
}
```

But here we got the second problem.

2) In automapper **version 4.2.1** (as I believe you downloaded from NuGet) the `Mapper` class has only `internal` constructors. It has a public constructors in documentation (which is weird) and I think will have in a future release.

Therefore, for now you need to modify `Load` method to use `option 1`:

```
public override void Load()
{
    this.Bind<AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration>().ToProvider<AutoMapperconfigurationProvider>().InSingletonScope();
    this.Bind<AutoMapper.IMapper>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper());
}
```

And then you can call `IMapper mapper = kernel.Get<IMapper>();` to get the mapper instance.

It will use `public IMapper CreateMapper() => new Mapper(this);` and will create the instance of IMapper. Note: you need to use MapperConfiguration (not IConfiguration provider) to call `CreateMapper` method, it has the same situation as with public/internal constructors of `Mapper`.

That should help.